# .htaccess - make parent address retain in browser address bar when rewriting to subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, address-bar

The site is in `public_html/directory/web/index.html` file.
Created `.htaccess` file to rewrite

```
domain.com/directory
```

into

```
domain.com/directory/web
```

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ web
```

.htaccess was in `directory` folder.

It worked but the address changed in browser addresse bar into `domain.com/directory/web`. How to retain the address `domain.com/directory`?

Answer (score 0):

File name should be added.

```
RewriteRule ^$ web/index.html
```